# Не работает .htaccess в директории /media/files/ в Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, apache, joomla

В директории /media/files/ лежит файл .htaccess с содержанием:

`Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all`

Но почему-то когда я запрашиваю доступ к какому-то файлу по адресу http://site.ru/media/files/FILENAME.zip, он спокойно скачивается, хотя должна быть ошибка 403 Forbidden. Что не так?

Comment: Когда обращаюсь к скриптам - .htaccess работает. А файлы скачиваются, что за дрянь?

Comment: У вас файлы может через php скрипт отдаются, а не напрямую их директории?

Answer (score 0):

```
<FilesMatch ~ "\.(zip|pdf|img|png)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Можешь добавить еще расширений

Comment: А толку, если без ограничений не работает, то с ограничениями начнет?